# Crystal Reports 2010 (V.13) shows no data in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: crystal-reports, vb.net-2010, crystal-reports-2010

I'm a newbie to VS and CR, and been struggling with this issue for days:
I've installed CR 2010 and tried creating a report on my VB.Net project - the report loads, shows the headers but there is no data.
When browsing each field in Field Explorer they too are empty.

- The database and dataset both have rows
- The report is as simple as they get - just displaying data from one table
- I created the report using the wizard, nothing was done manually

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried running the same query against the database? (There should be a menu option in the Crystal Reports Designer: Database > Show SQL Query...)

Comment: If you mean in Field Explorer->(Field)->Show SQL Query, then it's disabled...

Comment: Not from Field Explorer. If you are using the Crystal Reports Designer, there should be a `Database` menu option at the top of the screen; if you are editing the report in VS, you may be able to right-click in the report layout area and select `Database` from the dropdown menu. (Of course, if your report does not access a SQL datasource, then none of this is applicable.)

Comment: Disabled there as well. (Using SQL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took a while, but apparently the dataset passed was empty.
Here's the code to add to the form that holds the viewer (in case you're using MyBase.Load):

Private Sub test() Handles MyBase.Load

```
    Dim rpt As New TestReport
    Dim adp As New TestDataSetTableAdapters.CountriesTableAdapter
    Dim country As New TestDataSet.tblCountriesDataTable
    Dim ds As New DataSet()

    adp.Fill(country)
    ds.Tables.Add(country)

    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
    rpt.Load("TestReport.rpt")
    rpt.SetDataSource(ds)
    CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
```

End Sub

Comment: My Dear, This code works fine when there is only one table present in the crystal report. But when there are more than one tables, then it shows an error "Load Report Failed".. Any suggestions for this ??

Comment: You just need to add more adapters and datatables for each table.

e.g.:
Dim adp2 As New ...
Dim country2 As New...

adp2.Fill(country2)
ds.Tables.Add(country2)